# Error parsing XML, line 1940, column 65: The reference to entity "url" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing

So I got this error when I'm going to save my blogger template.
Here's the script :

```
var id = "d0f0e33bec6076b0a9e816d1bc2ab07c";
var redirect = "http://cur.lv/redirect.php?id=" + id + "&url=" ;
var links = $("a[href^='http']");
```

can some body help me? the error marked on "var redirect"
I need a quick response, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&amp;` instead of `&`:

```
var redirect = "http://cur.lv/redirect.php?id=" + id + "&amp;url=";
```

Now you have there invalid (and uknown) entity `&url` (`&url;` is expected) and XML parser returns an error there.

Comment: wow cool, it worked thanks. but I get another error on this code : for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { and the error says "Error parsing XML, line 1943, column 23: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." any help?

Comment: @MAnsyori: To answer that we need to see your XML. I think you should ask a new question. The original 'reference to entity "url"...' question has been answered.